# Where to ask general help for coding?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example, I have a question:
"Does CountDownLatch require the synchronized code?"

If you google it, there is no specific answer or detailed answer on why/why not it is required etc.

But, this is a specific question (I think), and there can be one answer, however, it seems a very "obvious" question and answer to certain programmers. Is that question appropriate for the SE/SO sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By quick research, I find that this is about Java API and **yes, it's programming related**. It's also specific, being a yes-no question. Finally, question that might be seem very obvious to certain programmers is okay, because then there are people that don't find it obvious (including you)... as long as you have done your part.

You could try **Stack Overflow**, but the question (as written now) doesn't show any research efforts. You <s>could</s> should add what you have researched and maybe your conclusion. It will be better if you could prepare a sample code with/without synchronized code to let others try it.

On top of that, you can then ask follow-up questions, such as "Are there any references that show if it does/doesn't need it?"